# Can't install my iOS 7 app to the iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit) iOS simulator

Tags: ios, ios7, ios-simulator, arm64

I can run my app on a physical 64-bit device it runs fine. Also I can install other test apps to the 64-bit sim. However when I try to run and build my app on the sim it acts like it is about to start by zooming in on the icon but then it freezes with the icon zoomed in then crashes but Xcode's debugger doesn't show anything. Any ideas?

EDIT: Works fine on non-64 bit sims. I have reset all iOS sims. (/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator). I have cleaned my project and build folder.

EDIT 2: When I start a new blank single view app it doesn't work either. So I think it's my Xcode install. The 'other' app that works in the 64-bit sim doesn't build a 64-bit binary.

Comment: Does it work fine on none 64 bit simulator?

Comment: Have you deleted the app in the sim? have you cleaned the project? have you cleaned your build folder?

Comment: @BooRanger I cleaned the sim folder, project, and build folder. Also I have recently reset my derived data.

Comment: @Eric Yes, other sims work fine.

Comment: Did you try iOS Simulator > Reset content and settings?

Comment: @JuJoDi Yes. I tried running it in the iPad 64-bit sim as well and it didn't install either.

Comment: Have you tried to comment out parts of your app to figure out where it may be crashing? I would probably start by changing the initial controller and seeing where the app actually stops opening

Comment: Could you please post the crash log in an edit

Comment: @JuJoDi Xcode acts like there hasn't been a crash.

Comment: Beta 5 came out today so I would suggest downloading it and seeing if it helps.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? Xcode > About Xcode

Comment: @JuJoDi Version 5.0.2 (5A3005)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling Xcode fixed the issue.

I wonder if I helped start this issue by side loading the iOS 6 SDK along side the iOS 7 SDK so that I could submit an iOS 6 app to the App Store with Xcode 5.

Comment: Thanks for posting the results. You can accept your own answer in a couple of days (and this is standard operating procedure). Might help others!

Comment: @matt Thanks, will do. I'll also note that when this issue had occurred I had already removed the iOS 6 SDK I had previously side loaded so maybe there was an issue with adding and removing the iOS 6 SDK.